# UIScrollView doesn't work well with IB

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I have a screen full of different UI objects that I need to scroll if on a 3.5 inch iPhone screen. I've added the ScrollView and setEnabled to YES but it still doesn't work. I'm thinking I should just code all the objects instead of using the IB and then add them to the scrollview. If I use a view with a scrollview on top with a view on top of that, then add them all to the subview, they lose their positioning. As for the constraints on the IB, there are simply too many objects and with hours spent on different constraint use, that will not be an option. Thanks for any suggestions and help.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot please?

Comment: The problem could be Autolayout constraints for the objects inside the scroll. Are you adding the objects inside the scroll from the IB?

Comment: I was but now am going to code them directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the content size to be the size your frame, which is this case your view controller since you mentioned its "a screen full of different UI objects"

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.scrollView.frame.size;
```

then set scrollView frame to be the size of the view's frame

```
self.scrollView.frame = self.view.frame;
```

Comment: shouldn't set any frames or contentsize attributes when using iOS7... should be using AUTOLayout

Comment: I guess that depends if he's using Auto-layout or not. But good point! thanks for that.

Comment: I'm using Autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

UIScrollView wont scroll, if the contents inside of the UIScrollview, are small enough to view without scrolling. 
So if you have a UIView obj inside of your UIScrollView and that UIView is not Bigger than the UIScrollView, by default the UIScrollview will not scroll.

Comment: When I run it on the 3.5, you can see the bar on the side scrolling but the actual screen doesn't move at all. When I run it on the 3.5, you can't see everything that is supposed to be on the screen.

Comment: that means the scrollview is atop the view, u wish to scroll, if im understanding you correctly